# Eloquent nested complex relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have some trouble with chaining relationships. I want to chain three of them, but this is not working properly:

```
    return UserModel::with('cars.pieces.attributes')
```

I want to retrieve a user with its cars. He chose a car which have pieces and for each pieces he chose an attribute.

With only `cars.pieces.` I have my user, then the array of cars then the array of pieces for this car. When I add attributes, I have attributes not for pieces of cars of users but attributes for pieces whatever cars it is.

It seems like the relationship is only looking for the previous relation and not the whole packet.

```php
    public function cars(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(CarsModel::class, 'user_cars', 'id_user','id_cars');
    }
```

Then

```php
    public function pieces(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(PiecesModel::class, 'cars_pieces', 'id_cars','id_pieces')
    }
```

And finally :

```php
    public function attributes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeModel::class, 'user_cars_pieces_attributes', 'id_attribute', 'id_piece')
    }
```

The last entity is using 4 fields for the primary key :

`id_user, id_car, id_attribute, id_piece`

What could be a way to retrieve attributes for pieces of cars of the user?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Are all those relationships defined in your user model?

Comment: @RobertKujawa Only cars relation is defined in my user model

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand why you have all these attributes in your 'last entity': `id_user, id_car, id_attribute, id_piece`, can you share your migrations?

Comment: The last entity is a model named `UserCarPiecesAttributes` which is related to the table `user_car_pieces_attributes`. I can share you the migrations, but how do you want them?

Comment: Ok, and you want to eager load cars -> pieces -> attributes?, but attributes must be related with user, car and piece all together right?

Comment: Exactly! More precisely, all cars have pieces  and there are not related to a user if it is clear... This is kind of a complex and strange relationship

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to your eager loading attributes:

```
return UserModel::with(['cars.pieces.attributes' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id_user', DB::raw('users.id'))->where('id_car', DB::raw('cars.id'));
}]);
```

I haven't tested this but I think it should work.

Remember to import DB Facade: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Comment: Ok so there is no apparent native way to eager load that deep? Interested about this callback I would try it. That way, the relation will be added to cars.pieces? Is this just an "extension" of attributes?

Comment: Did you want to eager load it to users directly? `user->attributes`?

Comment: Not at all, since I want to get all related attributes of a pieces in the list of car's user

Comment: Ok, let me know if the solution works for you, I'm still not sure if the `DB::raw()` expressions int the where clauses will work.

Comment: If this won't work I have a feeling that `whereRaw()` or `whereColumn()` should work, I will also test this when I get to my dev computer.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I will test it when I can. If it work I will put this answer as solving my problem

Comment: I just tested, this doesn't work, Laravel makes a new query for each nested eager loading relationship, which means that the previous level relations are not going to be part of the query. (So users and cars table data will not be available in the `DB::raw()`) The only way to achieve this is by using `join` to load the relations. Or looping through `users->cars->pieces` and manually loading the attributes relationship in there. But I don't recommend the latter.

Comment: The fact is that by using join to load it, it won't be part of the relation, would it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it won't be part of the relationship.